# restoring a variable after switching pages

Tags: flutter

i am new to flutter so am following some tuts about how it works. Now i've made a simple program where you can switch between 3 screens loading in the "main page"
code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testapp/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:testapp/pages/settings_page.dart';
import 'package:testapp/pages/profile_page.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FirstPage> createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final List _pages = [
    //home page
    const HomePage(),
    //profile page
    const ProfilePage(),
    //settings page
    const SettingsPage(),
  ];

  void _navigateBottomBar(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("1st Page"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 167, 64, 212),
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _navigateBottomBar,
          items: const [
            // home
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            // profile
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: 'Profile',
            ),
            // settings
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: 'Settings',
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the code for the page that has the counter on it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with RestorationMixin {
  final RestorableInt _counter = RestorableInt(0);
  int counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter.value++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    counter = _counter.value;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
            child: const Text("Home Page"),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 100, 0, 10),
            child: Text("You have aids $counter times!"),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: incrementCounter,
            child: const Text("Aids?"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  String? get restorationId => "home_screen";

  @override
  void restoreState(RestorationBucket? oldBucket, bool initialRestore) {
    registerForRestoration(_counter, "counter");
  }
}
```

now i am trying to save a counter value on one of the pages.
how ever when i switch a page and come back to it it resets. I've looked online about how to solve this and i've tried to use restorable ints but i hit a block when the tut loaded a new page with the push fuction which is different then my setup right now.

so i am curious of how to keep my counter after switching pages.
sorry if i didn't explain well, feel free to ask more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use the `IndexedStack` widget here. This will preserve the state of the pages.
In your `FirstPage` add the following code to the `body`.

```
body: IndexedStack(
 index: _selectedIndex,
 children: _pages
),
```

Comment: Would appreciate it if you can mark the answer as accepted if you found it useful.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.
i've inserted your code but i am met with an error:
The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.

any idea?

Comment: Change `final List _pages = [` to `final List<Widget> _pages = [`. That should do it

Comment: yes that did it, thank you very much! :)